# How do I use sessions in PHP?

Tags: php

i am building a php based website but now i need to give user a session, i.e the user can log in to website and have his session. after he should signout. how can i achieve this.?

Comment: You should use Php Session function, are well explained here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a $_SESSION["auth"] = true once the user logs in and the script which verifies the password should usually set the above session variable . then redirect to a restricted-to-members page like dashboard.php or photos.php using header(). Once the user logs out you should use session_destroy() function. Also its safer to have a session_regenerate_id(true) on every page so the session id cookie regenerated to prevent session hijacking.

```
<?php
session_start();//start session
session_regenerate_id(true); 
if($_SESSION["auth"] != true) {
header("Location: login.php"); // redirects to login if user is not logged in already
}
else {
//has access
if(!isset($_SESSION["timeout"])) {
$_SESSION["timeout"] = time();
}
else if(isset($_SESSION["time"])) {
if($_SESSION["timeout"] - time() == 1800) {
header("Location: login.php");//timeout incase no activity for 30min , 30min = 1800seconds

}

}

}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

on the beginning of every script put session_start()
Then create a database of users and their passwords.
When user logs in you should check his username and password, and if they match, put user id into session

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
```

In all scripts you can read this value $_SESSION['user_id'], so you know who is this user.

to logout use session_destroy

Answer (score 0):

Store any session-related data in your database or some other datastore with his username as the key. So when he logs in again, you could just load the data from the datastore and restore his session.

Any other session management system like the one with CodeIgniter or php's inbuilt session management should not be used for persistent sessions.

Comment: I guess that this is an advanced topic :)

Comment: Maybe I didn't the question right, but he wishes for the sessions to be persistent for a much longer duration, hence the suggestion.